# TCP Keep-alive does not detect a dead client

Tags: c, networking, tcp, keep-alive

I have added Keep-alive message in server in order to know about client. In my program server is keep on running and sending data to client. My problem is if client disconnect server never come to know that client get disconnected.

Below is the code snippet where i added keepalive

```
if ((newConnSD = ::accept(sockDesc, NULL, 0)) < 0) {
        throw SocketException("Accept failed (accept())", true);

 //TIMEOUT SETTING
 int buffersize = 4096;  

  setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&buffersize, 4);


 // KEEP ALIVE IMPLEMENTATION
  struct tcp_keepalive alive;
  DWORD dwBytesRet = 0;

    alive.onoff = TRUE;
    alive.keepaliveinterval = 1000;

    alive.keepalivetime = 60000;

    if (WSAIoctl(sockDesc, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &alive, sizeof(alive), NULL, 0,
    &dwBytesRet, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) failed; ");
        LOG4CXX_INFO(loggerToFile,"WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) failed ");
        cout<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        LOG4CXX_INFO(loggerToFile,"WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) Success ");
        cout<<"WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) Success " <<endl;
    }

  int optval;
   socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);
  /* Set the option active */
   optval = 1;
   optlen = sizeof(optval);
   if(setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE,(char*)&optval, optlen) < 0) {

       cout<<"Error while setting KEEP_ALIVE Message"<<endl;
       LOG4CXX_INFO(loggerToFile,"Error while setting KEEP_ALIVE Message");

   }
   else
   {
       LOG4CXX_INFO(loggerToFile,"SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket");
        cout<<"SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket"<<endl;
   }


 printf("SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS set:\n");
```

Comment: How are your code attempting to detect the timeout ? You'll have to read or write something to detect it.

Comment: Yes I am writing into the socket from another thread. renderManager->clientSocket->send(rasterBSONBuf, rasterBSONSize); renderManager->clientSocket->send("\nEOF", 4); But here send is just stuck in writing.

Comment: Why are you setting it twice?

Comment: Try changing the order of your calls. I think that the `setsockopt` is overriding the per connection settings (the timeouts to be specific) that you enabled with `WSAIoctl`.